# Display image from file path in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do you display an image from a location retrieved from a database?

I retrieve a list of locations (physical path) and have tried the methods below and no image is shown. I use SQL to store the file path (e.g. c:\123.jpg").

```
@model FoodSnap.ViewModels.FoodSnapViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Daily Review</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "FoodSnap"))
{   
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <img src="@Html.Raw(Model.ImageLocations[0])" alt="Image1" />
                <img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImageLocations[0])" alt="Image2" />
                <img src="@Model.ImageLocations[0]" alt="Image3" />
               style="width:150px;height:150px" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My Controller is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
        DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

        string fd1 = d1.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string ld1 = d2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        DateTime StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(fd1);
        DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ld1);           

        FoodSnapViewModel model = new FoodSnapViewModel
        {
           ImageLocations = new List<string>(from x in db.FoodType.OrderBy(x => x.fldTimeStamp).ToList() where x.fldUserId == User.Identity.GetUserId() && x.fldTimeStamp >= StartDate && x.fldTimeStamp < EndDate select x.fldImageId)
        };

        return View(model);          
    }
```

I am certainly passing the data to the View, but I cannot get the image to show using the path. I haven't use a byte stream into the database as I don't want to use it for storing images.

Any pointers would be appreciated...

Comment: What is the code your using to store the path. A path such as `c:\123.jpg` cannot work - you need to use virtual paths (using `Server.MapPath()`. You should have a folder in you app (say) `Images` and you save you images to that folder and the saved path will be `/Images/123.jpg`

Comment: If you wish to store the images in an offline (non-web-accessible) location then the URL in your image tag will need to point to an action method which can extract the content of the image from the file on disk and send it to the browser as if it were a download. Or you could use base64 to encode the images into the tag.

Comment: The code to save the file is as follows:  `code` string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyy-HHmmssffffff");string relativePath = "~/Content/UserImages/Originals/" + uploadFile.FileName;
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(relativePath);
                var p = "~/Content/UserImages/Originals/" + fileName + extension;                
                var physicalPath = Server.MapPath(p);

Answer (score 0):

I used @ADyson method and used the base64 method and it is working.

```
 public string GetImage(string file)
    {
        string imgPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/UserImages/Originals/" + file);
        byte[] byteData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imgPath);
        string imreBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(byteData);
        string imgDataURL = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", imreBase64Data);

        return imgDataURL;
    }
```